# How to generate random string only on certain time through excel file?

Tags: robotframework

#I need to generate random test strings for pass case and for fail case I need to give manual vale through excel file

#I have  tried:

#Give input to new bill cycle

```
[Arguments]    ${CYCLE_NAME}

${ret}=    Generate Random String    12        
 
input text    ${XPATH_TO_CYCLE_NAME_TEXTBOX}    ${CYCLE_NAME}
```

#and when I give `${ret}` on my excel file it says variable not found error.

Comment: i used data driver to read xlsx file and inside that i used ${ret}

Answer (score 0):

#thank all for you support i got the answer

*** Settings ***
Suite Setup    Initialize Random Variables

*** Keywords ***

Initialize Random Variables

```
     ${RANDOM_STRING}=   Generate random string        15
     Set global variable     ${RANDOM_CYCLE_NAME}
```

#Then i was able to call ${RANDOM_STRING} through my excel when ever i want random string